# How to Call Android Wireless & network settings from Phonegap 3.4?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In my Phonegap 3.4 application I have to  check the Network Connection before enter in to the application and in the conformation box I have to call the Android system's Wireless & Network setting page. Is there any custom plugin to do this task? Your response will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I have tried this answer [Best way to call activity Method with Phonegap 3.0 from js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606595/best-way-to-call-activity-method-with-phonegap-3-0-from-js) but not working in Phonegap 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

first u will call function that body in android activity class.Than on button click you can check that your internet connectivity is true or false.

This is html code sample:

```
<html>  <head>  <script language="javascript">  function js1() {
    document.loginform.method="post";  document.loginform.action = "https://example.com/chechlogin.asp";
           }
     </script>  </head>  <body>    <form name="loginform">
     <input type="text" name="empcode" value="58686" /><br/>
     <input type="password" name="emppassNTL" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_id" onclick="login.performclick();" />
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
          {
```

here is sample java class or android activity

```
   @JavascriptInterface
            public void performClick()
            {
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (null == ni)
    return false;
return ni.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }
          }, "login");
```