# Unable to connect to websocket

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, websocket

I have a cordova/phonegap app that is supposed to connect itself to a websocket server. It works fine on ios & android 4.4 but not on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 running android 4.2.

I know that the webview in 4.2 doesn't have a native implementation of WebSockets but I loaded a [phonegap plugin](https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android) for this. The plugin loads successfully and I waited for the deviceready event before attempting a connection. When I try the example provided by the plugin, the `onerror` event is trigered but I have no additionnal details.

Running the app using Google Chrome on the same device works, so I exclude a network issue. The application has the `INTERNET` permission. I'm a little out of clues at this point, any ideas are welcome :-)

Comment: Does adb show any additional output from the plugin itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after taking a look at the adb log as @Nicholas suggested (thanks!) I had an `exec() call to unknown plugin`. Somewhat following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974301/phonegap-3-plugin-exec-call-to-unknown-plugin) answer solved the problem.